# Why I dont need type definitions for node when working with Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I use nodejs with Typescript it allows me to use modules from nodejs (like `fs`) although I didn't install `@types/node`.

Why? Are they somehow baked in?

Comment: How do you use modules? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does require `@types/node`:

```
echo "import * fs fs from 'fs';" > test.ts
tsc test.ts
```

Results in

```
test.ts:1:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.

1 import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Then doing a

```
npm install @types/node
tsc test.ts
```

runs fine.

Do you possibly have @types/node installed globally?

Comment: Oh you are right! I have no idea how I got to think that it doesn't have to be there :( sorry

Answer (score 5):

When you are using a dependency which already has a dependency on `@types/node`, then you don't need to define the `@types/node` dependency yourself because it is hoisted.

You can find out if it is hoisted by running `yarn why @types/node`, which will show you information about [why a package is installed](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why/).